# Php and flash communication, multiplayer, local works, another computer does not

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, multiplayer

I made swf file that sends id to php, than php collects info from mysql by this id, and returns result, than flash does his work with that result.

The problem is here, I will try to explain it as clearly as I can:
everything works fine when I do that on the computer that has all the source files and of course xampp running.
but!!!
when I try to access this file form another computer in local network with
http://ip of host/playgame.php
"I try to make multiplayer game through flash and php and mysql exchanging info"
it loads swf file and dose not execute
loader.load(urlrequest);
the question is why????
the computer from localhost calls it but another computer in local network does not I found that by myself because on function serverResponse dose not execute simple code as txt.text="a";

So please help, why this dose not work form another computer in local network!

Comment: Try running `http://ip_of_host/playgame.php` in a web browser or `ping  ip_of_host` to check that your web server is accessible from the network. If it is not, I assume that you web server is configured to accept requests only from localhost, or maybe you are using IP address not visible to another computer, or local virtual host name not known on another computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crossdomain.xml should be added to another computer

[Cross-domain policy file specification](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/64389123/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf?version=1)

---

use charles proxy to check where exactly flash player requires crossdomain.xml

[charles proxy website](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)